# Exterior differential system on $SO(3;\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R$

Tags: exterior-algebra, differentials, differential-equations, lie-groups, manifolds

I have the following exterior differential system for one forms $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, where the $\theta^i$ are a cotangent basis on $SO(3)$, i.e. they satisfy $d \theta^i = \epsilon_{ijk} \theta^j \wedge \theta^k$ for the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon$:

$\theta^2 \wedge \alpha = 0$

$\theta^2 \wedge \gamma = 0$

$d \alpha = - \theta^3 \wedge \beta$

$d \beta = \theta^3 \wedge \alpha - \theta^1 \wedge \gamma$

$d \gamma = \theta^1 \wedge \beta$

In addition there is a coordinate $\rho$, i.e. the one forms can be expanded as $\alpha = \alpha_a \theta^a + \alpha_\rho d\rho$ etc.

I guess it doesn't look that imposing (I don't know much of EDSses), but I'm having a seminar talk in a few days, and I've still got plenty to do... It would be awesome if I had a solution to the system above to show the audience! I'd be happy with a proof of existence (a la Frobenius or something I guess) and SOME info on the solution as well or pointers to maybe similar systems in the literature. I'm aware of the text books by Bryant et al.[(Google books link)](http://books.google.fi/books?id=pPmHMAEACAAJ&dq=exterior+differential+systems&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YOKWUM3zBoem4gTAjoCYBQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA) and Ivey&Landsberg [(Google books link)](http://books.google.fi/books?id=8fxN1A7MLBQC&dq=exterior+differential+systems+ivey&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c-KWUKG4NOzb4QSt8oCgDA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA), but these are thick books and I'm almost outta time!!

I'll think about this myself too, of course, and I'll post here about it too, but now I need to get some sleep...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solutions are:

$ \alpha = a \theta^2, \qquad  \beta = -a \theta^1 - c \theta^3, \qquad \gamma = c \theta^2, $

where $a, c$ are constants.  (No $d\rho$ terms appear.)  Here's how the computation goes:

From your first two equations, we have

$ \alpha = a \theta^2, \qquad \gamma = c \theta^2$

for some functions $a, c$.  We can also assume that

$ \beta = b_1 \theta^1 + b_2 \theta^2 + b_3 \theta^3 + b_\rho d\rho$

for some functions $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_\rho$.

Now, substitute these expressions into your equation for $d\alpha$.  Reducing modulo $\theta^2$ implies that $b_\rho = 0$ and $b_1 = -a$.  Then the remaining terms imply that

$ da = a_2 \theta^2 - b_2 \theta^3$

for some function $a_2$. Similarly, reducing the equation for $d\gamma$ modulo $\theta^2$ implies that $b_3 = -c$, and then the remaining terms in $d\gamma$ imply that

$dc = b_2 \theta^1 + c_2 \theta^2$

for some function $c_2$.  Now, substitute all this into your equation for $d\beta$.  Reducing modulo $\theta^2$ implies that $b_2=0$, and then the remaining terms imply that $a_2 = c_2 = 0$ as well.  Therefore, $da = dc = 0$, and so $a$ and $c$ are constants, which leads to the solutions above.  (It is straightforward to check that these are, in fact, solutions for any constants $a, c$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeanne!! I guess rather than overthinking it, sometimes it's better to just go ahead and SOLVE that damn thing already! ;) Thanks also for the speed lesson in exterior differentials systems!

Comment: You're welcome!  And yes - sometimes direct computation works and sometimes it doesn't, but it's always worth a try.  :)

Comment: Jeanne: umm... you don't happen to be able to say something about another (more difficult) problem here?

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111578/another-exterior-differential-system-on-so3-mathbb-r-times-mathbb-r

It seems like this kind of systems would be best solved by a CAS package. I already found you Cartan package for Maple, but I guess it can't handle systems like this?

Comment: Well, I can take a look!  I'm kind of swamped this week, but I'll give it a try as soon as I get a chance.  

Comment: By the way, I fould your Cartan package for Maple. Will it be able to handle/solve this type of EDSes? I don't have access to Maple right now, but it could be useful in the future...

Comment: It might; I used it to do the calculations for this example, and I'll see what it can do for your other question when I get a chance. I'll let you know what I can come up with!